# How to disable weak ciphers in SSL?

Tags: ssl, encryption

We are getting weak cipher vulnerability during system scan and to resolve this I have negated them in string in `openssl.conf`, but still I am able to connect the local host using these ciphers, e.g. "RC4".

This vulnerability is reported on post 3128 and 8443 in the webserver.

**ssl.conf output:**

```
#SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4:!DES:!3DES
```

I'm still able to connect using the RC4 cipher to the local host.

```
[XXXXXXXXXX ~]$ openssl s_client -cipher 'RC4' -connect 127.0.0.1:3128
CONNECTED(00000003)
```

Is it the correct way to test, or I am doing something wrong?

Will this change in openssl.conf remove this weak cipher issue during the next scan?

Comment: the 1st line is the existing config and the 2nd is the modified config of ssl.conf

Answer (score 0):

Per [the Apache `SSLCipherSuite` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite) (bolding mine):

> This complex directive uses a colon-separated cipher-spec string
>   consisting of OpenSSL cipher specifications to configure the Cipher
>   Suite the client is permitted to negotiate in the SSL handshake phase.
>   **Notice that this directive can be used both in per-server and per-directory context.** ...

Without your entire `ssl.conf` file posted, it's impossible to know what's going on.

But I'd think the answer to your problem in any case is the easiest way to reliably configure SSL on a web server:  get your `ssl.conf` values directly from the [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/).  It's simple, repeatable, and well-documented.

Put in your system's specific software versions and required level of security, and you'll get back a set of configuration settings to place in your configuration files.

The site and its usage is full documented at [Mozilla's Security/Server Side TLS page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS):

> The goal of this document is to help operational teams with the
>   configuration of TLS on servers. All Mozilla sites and deployment
>   should follow the recommendations below.
>
> The Operations Security (OpSec) team maintains this document as a
>   reference guide to navigate the TLS landscape. It contains information
>   on TLS protocols, known issues and vulnerabilities, configuration
>   examples and testing tools. Changes are reviewed and merged by the
>   OpSec team, and broadcasted to the various Operational teams.
>
> ...
>
> [**Recommended configurations**](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_configurations)
>
> Three configurations are recommended. Pick the right configuration
>   depending on your audience. If you do not need backward compatibility,
>   and are building a service for modern clients only (post Firefox
>   27/Chrome 22), then use the Modern configuration. Otherwise, prefer
>   the Intermediate configuration. Use the Old backward compatible
>   configuration only if your service will be accessed by very old
>   clients, such as Windows XP IE6, or ancient libraries & bots.
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have checked the Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator, and after submitting the server and openssl versions, we are getting the cipher string as  shown below:

Comment: SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-C-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:

Comment: AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSSHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM

Comment: This was too long and i think has all the supported ciphers.

Comment: Also it suggest for SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

Comment: @Amar Well, those aren't *wrong*, even if they're awfully long.  If it does what you want, the length at least tells you explicitly what you've enabled without any guessing as to what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Henle, I also don't mean that it is wrong, but if we have already enabled all the HIGH and MEDIUM ciphers, i think all are activated, and then we remove those which are causing vulnerablities, thats why I used " :!RC4:!DES:!3DES " will it help to disable RC4 and DES ciphers.

Comment: Your question is based on that `!RC4` not working.  If you use the configuration settings from the Mozilla tool, does your `openssl s_client ...` test still connect using `RC4`?